# how to add kiss fft in visual studio 2012 and making sure added?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

How can I add `kiss fft` library to a `visual studio 2012` project?
Because I want to compile this code:

```
#include "kiss_fft.h"
#include "kiss_fftr.h"

kiss_fft_cpx* copycpx(float *mat, int nframe)
{
    int i;
    kiss_fft_cpx *mat2;
    mat2=(kiss_fft_cpx*)KISS_FFT_MALLOC(sizeof(kiss_fft_cpx)*nframe);
        kiss_fft_scalar zero;
        memset(&zero,0,sizeof(zero) );
    for(i=0; i<nframe ; i++)
    {
        mat2[i].r = mat[i];
        mat2[i].i = zero;
    }
    return mat2;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i,size = 12;
    int isinverse = 1;
    float buf[size];
    float array[] = {0.1, 0.6, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.6, 0.1,0};  

    kiss_fft_cpx out_cpx[size],out[size],*cpx_buf;

    kiss_fftr_cfg fft = kiss_fftr_alloc(size*2 ,0 ,0,0);
    kiss_fftr_cfg ifft = kiss_fftr_alloc(size*2,isinverse,0,0);

    cpx_buf = copycpx(array,size);
    kiss_fftr(fft,(kiss_fft_scalar*)cpx_buf, out_cpx);
    kiss_fftri(ifft,out_cpx,(kiss_fft_scalar*)out );

    printf("Input:    tOutput:n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
    buf[i] = (out[i].r)/(size*2);
    printf("%ft%fn",array[i],buf[i]);
    }

    kiss_fft_cleanup();   
    free(fft);
    free(ifft);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a second project inside my solution, and manually added the `kiss_fft` source files. Then I told Visual Studio that my own project depended on the `kiss_fft` project.

To do this, you need to do TWO things (MSVC++ is not very smart here). Using the Solution Explorer, right click on your project and select "Build Dependencies" in This menu contains "Project dependencies". That's the simple one. The second step is harder to find: right click again on your project, and this time open the properties dialog. The very top group "common properties" contains "Common properties>references"  and here you have to "Add New Reference"  to kissfft.